# How to assort files of an executable python3 program made with cx_freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I developed a project in python 3.4.1 and pyqt4. Then I converted my python program to executable file using `cx_freeze` module.

Everything is perfectly fine, but I found two problems here:

1. Size of program gets really high.
2. I like to assort my files in special folders by their format type, for example all of the .dll files in a folder called DLL and something like that, but when I do this I ran into some problems.

Is it really possible ? If yes give me some information and if no, what can I do to solve my problems. Thanks

Error I get :

> cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line
>   27, in 
>       exec(code, m.**dict**)   File "MY APP.py", line 1, in    File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in
>   _find_and_load   File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in
>   _load_unlocked   File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in
>   _load_backward_compatible   File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt4_QtCore.py", line 22, in    File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt4_QtCore.py", line
>   21, in **bootstrap** ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore

Comment: It is possible but I don't have my scripts anymore :/
The programm will get really big, cause of qt and of the python interpreter. (I think it will be around 25 Mb)

Comment: If you have any solution please give it to me.